# Inheritance in JPA not working

Tags: java, jpa

I have a parent class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseText implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "LOCALE_CODE", nullable = false)
    private String localeCode;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Index
    @Column(name = "LOCALIZED_TEXT_ID", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey
    private LocalizedText localizedText;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

And one of the sub classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSESSMENT_TEXT")
@AttributeOverride(name = "localeCode", column = @Column(name = "LOCALE_CODE"))
@AssociationOverride(name = "localizedText", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LOCALIZED_TEXT_ID"))
public class AssessmentText extends BaseText {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Index
    @Column(name = "ASSESSMENT_ID", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey
    private Assessment assessment;

    //Getters and setters.
}
```

When I am trying to persist an object I get the following error:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Superclass field "java.lang.Object.localizedText" is mapped in the metadata for subclass "com.my.com.AssessmentText", but is not a persistent field.
```

What is causing this and how to solve it?

I am using embedded derby database in JUnit and the JPA implementation is OpenJPA.

Comment: does LocalizedText implements Serializable ?

Comment: Yes, all the entities implements Serializable.

Comment: just a side note, the overrides are a bit pointless, nothing is being changed,. You are overriding them to the same values :)

Comment: Why do you have the Column on the localizedText mapping?  It should just have the ManyToOne with possibly a joinColumn annotation to define the column if needed.  I'm not sure how OpenJPA would handle it, but a Column annotation would be expected with a basic mapping and might be conflicting with your ManyToOne.

Comment: It was my stupid mistake. I forgot to add BaseText class into the persistence.xml file of OpenJPA. Also I removed the *..Override annotations and added @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is the solution, but I miss an @Inheritance annotation from AssessmentText:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSESSMENT_TEXT")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@AttributeOverride(name = "localeCode", column = @Column(name = "LOCALE_CODE"))
@AssociationOverride(name = "localizedText",
                     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LOCALIZED_TEXT_ID"))
public class AssessmentText extends BaseText {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it by adding the MappedSuperClass to the persistence.xml.

I know this is also in the comments somewhere, but the useful one was hidden and I think this should be an answer, not a comment to the question.